Cold water in BR does not flow
We have a kohl’s two handle nickel faucet.  The cold water does not flow when opening the valve

Disconnect the supply hose from the faucet, and see if that flows.
If not, you have a closed valve or other blockage in the supply line.
If it does, you have a blockage in the faucet or a defective faucet.

What's the possibility somebody installing the faucet  was using PTFE tape to seal the threads and got a layer of the tape fully over the end or the pipe and thus creating a diaphragm which has blocked the water flow?

Pretty limited - it tends to stretch and rupture if unsupported.
